# Strange behavior of MySQL IMPORT

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, windows

**On Windows platform (Windows7)**

I am trying to import a database form .sql file through command prompt by using following command

> mysql -u username -p database-name < path-of-file\filename.sql

It runs successfully.

But If I use semicolon at the end of the command

> mysql -u username -p database-name < path-of-file\filename.sql;

It is not showing any error/warning but printing mysql help document and import fails

**On Linux Platform (Ubuntu)**

Both import(With semi-colon & without semi-colon) work fine.

**My MySQL Version** : 5.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows command line (cmd.exe) is not a POSIX-shell, as most likely your Linux shell is. This means ; are treated differently -- the ; is interpreted by your shell and not by your MySQL client.